# How to implement logic based on a relationship matrix

Tags: c++, logic, relationship

Consider that I have a symmetrical relationship matrix, similar to this: [image]

Except that each "outcome" is a small piece of code.

My scenario: I have a bunch of `Entity` objects that "collide" with eachother. Each entity has a `CollisionType` value (an enum). In the design, a relationship matrix exists which describes how the entities behave when different CollisionTypes meet each other.

I'm wondering: How would I represent the relationships, and also implement logic on top of it,  in an clean and high-performance manner which is easy to add new CollisionTypes to? In my mind it looks something like a 2D Switch statement.

Example (poor) solution:

```
void CollideEntities( Entity e1, Entity e2 ) {
    CollisionType t1 = e1.GetCollisionType();
    CollisionType t2 = e2.GetCollisionType();

    // perform basic logic based on t1 & t2
    if ( (t1 == COL_SOLID && t2 == COL_SQUISHY) || (t1 == COL_SQUISHY && t2 == COL_SOLID) ) {
        // do stuff..
    } else if ( (t1 == COL_SOLID && t2 == COL_DAMAGE) || (t1 == COL_DAMAGE && t2 == COL_SOLID) ) {
        // do other stuff..
    } // and so on...

}
```

Many potential solutions are apparent to me, but none of them strike me as particularly clean or efficient or easy to add new types to...

Comment: As long as you don't tell us what you intend to do with the data any suggestion will probably be futile. E.g. you can represent this as a graph or a 2D boolean matrix but that would depend on what you intend to achieve with this.

Comment: I intend to compare the data and execute some code based on the relationship. The data is an enum on an object (as per the example) and the representation of the relationship is exactly what I'd like advice on. (i.e. right now I'm representing it as a series of if statements.)  Expanding the quetsion to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Symmetric_matrix {
  private:
    size_t size1;
    // The next should be <bool> rather than <int>,
    // but the writer's compiler objects.
    std::vector<int> outcomes;
  public:
    size_t size() const { return size1; }
    int &operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) {
        const size_t a = i <= j ? i : j;
        const size_t b = i <= j ? j : i;
        return outcomes[(b*(b-1))/2 + a];
    }
    Symmetric_matrix(const size_t size0)
      : size1(size0), outcomes((size()*(size()-1))/2, false) {}
};

// Here is a test driver.
int main() {
    Symmetric_matrix sm(5);
    sm(0, 1) = true;
    sm(0, 3) = true;
    sm(1, 3) = true;
    sm(2, 3) = true;
    sm(3, 4) = true;
    std::cout << "buyer-approver      : " << sm(0, 2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "approver-buyer      : " << sm(2, 0) << "\n";
    std::cout << "approver-requisition: " << sm(2, 3) << "\n";
    std::cout << "requisition-approver: " << sm(3, 2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Your question is an interesting one.  As you have observed, one need only store the upper or the lower triangle of the matrix, not both.

But what's the `(b*(b-1))/2` about, you ask?  Answer: it comes of the curious arithmetical fact that 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (b-1) == (b*(b-1))/2 (try it).

Of course, my sample code could stand some improvement.  For one thing, for some reason (advice is requested), my code fails when it uses a `std::vector<bool>`, so I have used a `std::vector<int>` as a workaround.  For another, it does not include proper handling for the case `i == j`.  What it does do however is to convey the essential technique.  You can fill out details at your discretion.

(*Update:* It has later occurred to my why the `std::vector<bool>` fails.  It fails because `std::vector<bool>` is implemented as an array of bits, whereas a single bit cannot be an *lvalue* because it has no address of its own.  With clever coding, by having the `operator()()` return a manipulator of some specially defined type, one could probably finesse the problem without altering `main()`, but it is probably easiest just to define and use a `set()` member function if the `<bool>` is what we want to use.)

Comment: Wow, that is an amazing indexing trick! I'm going to have to keep that in my pocked whether I use it for this problem or not...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it that way.  I'd have a Map where the key would look up a Command object containing the desired behavior.

Another possibility would be a Visitor pattern (aka "double dispatch").

Comment: I've done this with `Visitor`, worked well, easy to maintain.

Comment: How would you suggest keying the map?  It's also not clear to me how I use Visitor here, it's not a pattern I'm familiar with.

Comment: Visitor is a Gang of Four pattern.  Certainly "double dispatch" or "multiple dispatch" goes back a long way.  I don't know how you'd key it - that's a proof left for the student.  Maybe it's "type1-type2" string or something, with the same value for "type2-type1".  Easy.